# Отсутствуют переводы во вкладке "Активность" в профиле участника

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

Сейчас идёт [процесс приведения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049) вкладки ["Активность"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) профиля участника к адаптивному дизайну. В связи с этим многие переводы требуется обновить.

Comment: печально, что самый тупой дизай, какой только можно придумать, стали называть resposinve (в каком именно месте там адаптивность?) и использовать везде.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, много видел уже

Comment: я к сожалению не вижу, какое разделение голосов на мете по поводу этого нововведения, но сегодня утром у того поста было +7 (остатки предварительного обсуждения), а сейчас -47.

Comment: @Эникейщик на текущий момент (+48/-179).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Б**о**льшую часть перевёл. Есть некоторые проблемы из-за ошибок на стороне разработчиков. Заведены соответствующие баг-репорты на MSE:

- [<s>Недоступно для перевода "Accepted answer", "Summary", "View answer"</s>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372733#372733)
- [Наложение текста](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372732#372732)
- [Скачет панель кнопок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372731#372731)
- [Окончание для `k` показов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372815/339911)

Голосуйте за важные для вас пункты на MSE. Там их много под [вопросом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/339911) собралось.

Ещё возникла интересная [проблема по формулировке текста](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/468428/183872) с количеством сообщений.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам